# Newbie: C# List returns back System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, list, collections, foreach

Seems this would be pretty simple:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("String 1");
        lst.Add("String 2");

        foreach (string item in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lst);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

However it returns:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Comment: You're writing the lst object instead of the item object

Comment: DUH!!! I can't believe I made that mistake. Makes sense now.

Comment: don't worry about it. Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
foreach (string item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lst));
```